# php curl PUT request

Tags: php-curl

I am trying to send a PUT request using curl php but I am getting `"status":103,"message":"Invalid JSON Request"` as response.

```
$data = array('request'=>'personalized-accounts',
'name'=>'john doe',
'reference'=>'162329305158',
'email'=>'ade@gmail.com');
$url = 'https://demo.api.gladepay.com/resources';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
  'MID: GP0000001',
  'KEY: 123456789',
  'Content-Type:application/json'

));
$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo $response;
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

As your `Content-Type` is `application/json` but you are sending post data in url-encoded mode which might triggered the error.
Change this line

> `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));`

to like below

> `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($data));`

for sending the json data in post request.

Comment: welcome , accepting the answer might help others to know that this solution will work if they face the same error like you. :)